# Command prompt not closing after starting wampserver from it

Tags: batch-file

```
net start Apache2.2
wampmanager
chrome --new-window "http://localhost:8090/form.html"
```

This is the batch file that I am using to start the apache server, wampserver and then open the url in a new chrome window.

But when I run this the command window gets stuck on wampmanager and hence does not proceed with opening the html page.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
start wampmanager
```

Not that I know - or want to know - what wampmanager is. This should cure the problem.

Comment: What should be done if I wish to run the third command only when the previous ones finish executing ?

Comment: see `START /?` from the prompt. `START /WAIT` will wait for the `START`ed item to close before proceeding - but isn't your problem that this `wampmanager` isn't returning? Oh - perhaps it's a batch. If it's a batch, then you should `CALL WAMPMANAGER`. If you simply execute a batch file from another batch file, control is transferred to the new batchfile, never to return...if you call it, then return will be done when the second batch finishes.